# Let $x, y, $ and $z$ be selected uniformly and independently at random over the interval $(0, 3)$. What is the probability that $x + y + z > 1$?

Tags: probability, geometry, random-variables

I am having trouble finding the number of possible combinations for this problem:

Question:

> Let $x$, $y$, and $z$ be selected uniformly and independently at random over the interval $(0, 3)$. What is
>   the probability that $x + y + z > 1?$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Are $x, y, z$ are integers?

Answer (score 1):

You select a uniformly distributed random point $(x,y,z)$ in the cube $C:=[0,3]^3$. Draw a figure! Find the set $B\subset C$ of "bad" points (where $x+y+z\leq 1$),  compute the probability $P(B)$, and finally $P(C\setminus B)$.

Answer (score 1):

An analytic approach

$1-\frac {\int_0^1\int_0^{1-z}\int_0^{1-y-z} \ dx \ dy\ dz}{\int_0^3\int_0^3\int_0^3 \ dx \ dy\ dz}$

Or if you prefer

$\frac {\int_0^3\int_{1-z}^{3}\int_{1-y-z}^{3} \ dx \ dy\ dz}{\int_0^3\int_0^3\int_0^3 \ dx \ dy\ dz}$

A Geometric approach

$x+y+z \le 1$ with $x,y,z > 0$ defines a tetrahedron -- the volume under the plane in the first quadrant.

What is the volume of the cube less the tetrahedron compared to the volume of the cube?